# Lua decimal precision loss

Tags: lua, precision

Can someone explain why in lua running:

```
return 256.65 * 1000000 + .000000005 - 256 * 1000000 gives 649999.99999997
```

whereas

```
return 255.65 * 1000000 + .000000005 - 255 * 1000000 and 
return 268.65 * 1000000 + .000000005 - 268 * 1000000 give 650000.0 ?
```

From what i can see it seems to be an issue strictly for decimal 65 (and it seems also 15) and for whole numbers within the range 256 - 267. I know this is related to doing these calculations with floating points, but I'm still curious as to what is special about these values in particular

Comment: When printing a number `x` by issuing command `print(x)`, Lua shows you `string.format("%.14g", x)` instead of all available digits of number `x` (see [Lua source](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/luaconf.h.html#LUA_NUMBER_FMT)). You can try `print(string.format("%.17g", x))` to view more digits.

Comment: Your 2nd code snippet is invalid.

Comment: What do you mean it is invalid? To be clear I meant them as 2 separate code snippets not 2 return statements and ed together. I apologize if this was unclear

Answer (score 2):

What is special about these values is that 0.65 is not a binary fraction (even though it is a decimal fraction), and so cannot be represented exactly in floating point.

For the record, this is not specific to Lua. The same thing will happen in C.

Comment: Right, but neither is .64 and that doesnt have this issue. Furthermore, that doesnt explain why it doesnt happen with 252.65 for example

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that 10/3 is a repeating fraction in base 10. In base 3, dividing by 3 would result in whole numbers. In base 2 -- which is used to represent numbers in a computer -- the numbers you're producing similarly result in fractions that can be exactly represented.

[Further reading.](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

Comment: Yes I understand all that. I still don't understand what's magic about the range 255 to 268. If you are saying it's because .65 cannot be represented precisely then why doesn't that happen for 259.65. Also why doesn't this happen for .64 or any other decimal that can't be represented precisely in binary